How to view Parallels VM Django webserver from Mac Sequoia host browser?
I've been running a Django webserver in an Ubuntu 22.04 VM using Parallels (Standard Edition Version 20.0.1) on my M2 Mac.
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
I then view the website in Chrome/Safari/Firefox on my Mac OS, pointing the browser to the IP of the VM at port 8000.
http://ip.of.ubuntu.vm:8000
It's always worked great.
But yesterday I upgraded my MacOS to Sequoia 15.0. Now I can't see the website served from the VM in the host browser anymore.
I've tried switching VM > Configure > Hardware > Network > Source from Shared Network to Default Adapter, and also to WiFi, but those did not help.
I can ping the VM's IP from the MacOS in Terminal and it finds it. But the browser cannot see the website. Chrome tells me:
This site can’t be reached
http://ip.of.ubuntu.vm:8000/donate/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

I've restarted everything. That hasn't helped.
As a workaround, I can, of course, view the site in Ubuntu. That works properly. But I'd like to be able to see it in the host Mac also.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!
